# Safely unlocking a Facebook achievement without a server component?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook, secret-key

Unlocking a Facebook achievement requires you to use an application access token rather than a user access token - presumably so that users cannot unlock their own achievements with a graph API call.  The application token is a combination of your app id (public knowledge) and your application secret key (private).  This is easily accomplished when your application has a server component as you can safely embed your application secret key in the server code without fear of it leaking and simply request that your server unlock the achievement when its conditions are met.  However, if your application doesn't have a server component (ie: it's a native iOS or Android application) then it doesn't seem possible to unlock the achievement without embedding the secret key in your application binary (a Bad Thing).  Is there a recommended means to accomplish this without a server or do you really need to have one if you're not willing to embed your secret key?

Comment: Great question about where to store the secret key!